# Combining LUIS and QNA Maker models, run in Entity List limits

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Within our organization we use the Microsoft bot-framework to create our chatbot. Since August last year, we implemented the Virtual Agent (VA) + Skill layout and for every Skill we have our separate LUIS model. Besides, we use the QnA Maker technology to react on FAQs. In order to create the Dispatch LUIS model we combine the Skill models with the Microsoft Dispatch-CLI. With ever increasing number of Skills and growing Skill dialogs we currently run in the following problem: the Dispatch LUIS model can not be generated due to the Entity List Limit (50, see: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-limits) )

Our Skills are subject based and to improve intent recognition within the Skill LUIS model we use patterns. According to documentation, every pattern is added to the Dispatch LUIS model and if an entity is added to the pattern also this entity is added to the Dispatch LUIS model.

This means that if you hit the maximum accepted amount of entity lists in a model and you add patterns in order to improve intent recognition, also the Dispatch LUIS model will automatically hit the maximum amount. But this also means that if you add more Skills with individual LUIS models to your VA the Dispatch LUIS model will eventually hit the maximum number of accepted entities. We do need to use entities, so we can switch between sub-subjects and we can add synonyms to sub-subjects. As an example*:

what does a XXX cost, Where XXX can be car (synonym: vehicle) or bicycle (synonym: bike).

Did anybody experience the same issue and how did you solve this, or are we using the LUIS model structures incorrectly? On behalf of the team, we look forward to your insights.

*Our model is using more advanced structures and utterances

Comment: Do you still need help?